# OpenGL [realtime] 360 camera possible?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

Is it possible to render a 360 equirectangular OpenGL view from camera? I already know to set it up on Cycles and BI, but I would like to know if it is possible to set this kind of camera to make a realtime render of the OpenGL view for speed render purposes.

Comment: No I don't think it is As far as I know this is not supported in OpenGL yet. Otherwise we'd be able to get panoramic camera previews in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You can take 6 rectangle cameras with 90° FOV, which head to East, West, North, South, Up, Down. Then you get faces of a cubebox.
You can map the cubebox into equirectangular in a simple fragment shader or use it directly.